# Webpack Datatables import issue - JS errors "Cannot read properties of undefined"

Tags: jquery, webpack, datatables, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to get Datatables + Bootstrap + jquery to work nicely together in a Symfony 6 project.
This all works fine and nicely as long as I don't use the datatables buttons.
Once I include the buttons (or try to), then errors that could indicate a jquery mismatch (between the installed version and the version expected by datatables) arise.
However, I don't think this is the REAL cause since I have a project using the same versions where however the datatables buttons do work.

I've the following config (minimized to the maximal extend):

App.js:

---

```
import './styles/app.scss';

import jquery from 'jquery'; window.$ = window.jQuery = jquery;

import 'datatables.net'; import 'datatables.net-bs5'; import 'datatables.net-buttons'; import 'datatables.net-buttons-bs5'; import 'bootstrap';

$(document).ready(function() {   $('#myTable').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'print'
    ]   }); });
```

relevant part of my package.json:

---

```
 "dependencies": {
      "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
      "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.5",
      "datatables.net": "^1.13.5",
      "datatables.net-bs5": "^1.13.5",
      "datatables.net-buttons-bs5": "^2.4.1",
      "datatables.net-colreorder-bs5": "^1.7.0",
      "datatables.net-keytable-bs5": "^2.10.0",
      "datatables.net-responsive-bs5": "^2.5.0",
      "datatables.net-rowgroup-bs5": "^1.4.0",
      "datatables.net-searchpanes-bs5": "^2.2.0",
      "datatables.net-select": "^1.7.0",
      "datatables.net-select-bs5": "^1.7.0",
      "dragula": "^3.7.3",
      "flatpickr": "^4.6.13",
      "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
      "jquery": "^3.7.0",
      "jquery-contextmenu": "^3.0.0-beta.2",
      "jquery-ui": "^1.13.2",
      "jsv": "^1.0.0",
      "jszip": "^3.10.1",
      "moment": "^2.29.4",
      "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
      "pdfmake": "^0.2.7",
      "webpack": "^5.88.2"
  },
```

I always get this error:

---

```
buttons.bootstrap5.mjs:13  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'defaults')
    at ./node_modules/datatables.net-buttons-bs5/js/buttons.bootstrap5.mjs (buttons.bootstrap5.mjs:13:25)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at ./assets/app.js (app.js:17:84)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at __webpack_exec__ (app.scss:1:1)
    at app.scss:1:1
    at __webpack_require__.O (chunk loaded:23:1)
    at app.scss:1:1
    at webpackJsonpCallback (jsonp chunk loading:34:1)
    at app.js:2:77
```

The other files (webpack.conf etc) I can provide but I think the issue should lie somewhere in the code I provided.
npm run watch doesnt give any errors.
It's, I think, not related to this question:
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/77675/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-classname-in-symfony-stimulus-webpack

I tried to use the
https://debug.datatables.net/ - as expected (due to the fact its an import issue) this only works on the "working" scenario, so with the buttons not imported
(

```
//  import 'datatables.net-buttons';
//  import 'datatables.net-buttons-bs5';
```

) and this results in in this -> https://debug.datatables.net/uwoqaj

Please let me know if you have any ideas

where the problem lies ?
how I can troubleshoot this kind of issues in the (edge) browser ?